# flowcover remove mirror from images at bottom

Tags: iphone, ios, coverflow

I am using this library for implementing coverflow in my app
http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.html

Now I would like to remove mirror from images as you can see in the above link. It is developed in opengl. Can anybody please tell me how to remove mirror of images from it?

Thanks
Ayaz Alavi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this method in FlowCoverView.m file will remove mirror effect.

```
- (void)drawTile:(int)index atOffset:(double)off
{
FlowCoverRecord *fcr = [self getTileAtIndex:index];
GLfloat m[16];
memset(m,0,sizeof(m));
m[10] = 1;
m[15] = 1;
m[0] = 1;
m[5] = 1;
double trans = off * SPREADIMAGE;

double f = off * FLANKSPREAD;
if (f < -FLANKSPREAD) {
    f = -FLANKSPREAD;
} else if (f > FLANKSPREAD) {
    f = FLANKSPREAD;
}
m[3] = -f;
m[0] = 1-fabs(f);
double sc = 0.45 * (1 - fabs(f));
trans += f * 1;

glPushMatrix();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,fcr.texture);
glTranslatef(trans, 0, 0);
glScalef(sc,sc,1.0);
glMultMatrixf(m);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,4);

// reflect
    //  glTranslatef(0,-2,0);
    //  glScalef(1,-1,1);
    //  glColor4f(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5);
    //  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,4);
    //  glColor4f(1,1,1,1);

glPopMatrix();
```

}